# How to add zero in decimal number in hive.?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have some data in my hive table which have different number of tailing digits after decimal, I used decimal(precision,scale) function so that i can get data with two tailing digit after decimal.
for decimal(10,2) function-
input 123.123
output 123.12

but for input 123.1
output was 123.1 and i want it to be 123.10
How can i get data in my desired format.?

Comment: If you are not happy with the default formatting, then convert the DECIMAL to STRING with `printf()` and a Java format string.

Answer (score 0):

Tailing 0 after decimal getting trim for release prior to 0.14 in Hive. This issue is fixed in 0.14 release. Jira Id for reference :- 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7373